# LAN servers aren't working

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm playing on Minecraft PE v1.1.5 and my bro can't join my world my WiFi is the same, LAN is on. I can join his worlds but he can't join mine.

Comment: Make sure that you have enabled "Broadcast to LAN" so others can join your world.

Comment: Also, make sure that you are using the same version of Minecraft.